# Dynamixel X with OpenCM 9.04C and ROS possible or OpenCR/U2D2 need?

Tags: ros, dynamixel, ros-lunar, opencr, dynamixel-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I plan to build a robot arm with Dynamixel X servos. I also want to use ROS tools and drivers for the servos. I found there is a cheap OpenCM 9.04C Controller board (~20USD) available, also the U2D2 USB Interface (~50USD) and then the OpenCR Board (~200USD). In the ROS packages I only found the OpenCR mentioned. My plan is that ROS runs on the PC and I just need the interface from there to Dynamixel X. My question is: Can I control the Dynamixel X (T version with 3 cables) on ROS through the OpenCM 9.04 board? And can you name me the ROS packages I need for this? Or do I need to buy one of the 2 other boards (U2D2 or OpenCR)?

Thank you for any help, I'm new to Dynamixel ;-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313901/dynamixel-x-with-opencm-9.04c-and-ros-possible-or-opencr/u2d2-need?/) by [Johannes Jaegers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10981/johannes-jaegers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2019-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your inquiry about Dynamixels.

To control Dynamixels on your PC, you are supposed to need U2D2 (http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/interface/u2d2/) and U2D2 power hub (http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/interface/u2d2_power_hub/)

The releated packages are showing

DynamixelSDK and Dynamixel-Workbench

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/DynamixelSDK
https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2019-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2019-09-10**:
Hi, good to see this post. I have the similar situation. I have RPi3+openCM904 and i am willing to use ROS with this configuration. Can I go with configuring ROS on "RPi3+openCM9.04+Dynamixel"? If YES, please help me to setup the supported library and development. Please guide me accordingly~ Thanks! Best Regards, /Ash